# Emacs M-x sql-postgres encryption

Tags: postgresql, encryption, emacs

Is it possible to encrypt the connection established with `M-x sql-postgres` in Emacs? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sql-postgres` uses psql, so you can use whatever psql and libpq accept.  You could for example set the environment variable `PGSSLMODE=require`.

There might be a better way, but the `sql-mode` in Emacs is pretty ancient with respect to PostgreSQL support.

Comment: Also note that psql will helpfully print out `SSL connection` after starting, which sql-mode will echo.  This makes it easy to confirm it's connected securely.